# how to group entries in an activity stream

Tags: social-networking

We currently have an activity stream for things like users posting a photo, liking a post, and commenting.  Everyone essentially has their own stream which I fan out to on write.  I want to group similar activity stream entries together like Facebook does.  E.g. "Jim, Mary and John liked your post" shows up as one entry rather than 3 entries, one for Jim, Mary and John separately.

Does that mean I shouldn't use fan-out on write anymore and would have to change my architecture?  Or, should I still keep my activity streams as is and group and process entries on read?  Are there things I can do to make that more efficient?  What are some best practices on how to group activities together, like maybe all entries of the same type in the past day, past hour, or since last login should be grouped together?

Should I do this client-side?  Should I have an auto-incrmenting incrementing group by integer for each feed item that's tied to some time period?

Comment: I am starting to flesh out an activity stream with the same requirements as yours. Did you end up implementing with fan-out on write?

Comment: I did fan out on write, but we are actually looking to re-architect it so that it's aggregates on read... it made maintenance a bit of a headache and also didn't let you get any back data as it would only start writing to your stream when you subscribe